# Django Testing: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing

i faced a weird issue while trying to run the unit test in Django, this works fine for the API but only have this issue while running the test.

i think i need to have same configuration but i am not sure how i can achieve this in Django test, also i tried to rename the testing database to one that i manually created bit it does not sounds the tests are being executing in that database "Not sure if i correctly configure the testing setting"

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "NAME": "my_database",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": 5435,
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": "mytestdatabase",
            "USER": "postgres",
            "PASSWORD": "postgres",
            "HOST": "localhost",
            "PORT": 5435,
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Python/Django are you using and can you add the traceback to your question? Check if you use a different settings file when testing

Comment: i am using Python 3.10.1
and Django 4.0

Comment: also i only have one settings file for the project
the weird thing is that it runs on the API "when running the server "manage.py runserver" but it give me issues when running "manage.py test" !!!

Comment: @AmeenKharma did you solve the issue in some way? some issue here... Thank you